# Как получить data feed?

Tags: java, csv, io

Здравствуйте. Есть, к примеру, такой url 
http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv
если его ввести в браузер, то скачивается файл в формате csv. Все работает нормально. Я же пытаюсь программно получить содержимое этого файла в строковую переменную:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MyStockQuote {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlCon = null;
        InputStreamReader inStream = null;
        BufferedReader buff = null;
        String csvString;
        try{
            url = new URL("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv");
            urlCon = url.openConnection();
            inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream());
            buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);

            csvString =buff.readLine();
            System.out.println(csvString);   
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
             System.out.println("Please check the spelling of " 
                     + "the URL: " + e.toString() );
} catch(IOException  e1){
System.out.println("Can't read from the Internet: " + 
                                  e1.toString() ); 
}
finally{
try{
  inStream.close();
  buff.close();   
}catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("StockQuote: can't close streams" + e.getMessage());
}
}  

    }

}
```

но результат - `<HTML>`
Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам.Документ сменил url.
Если в через цикл вывести весь документ, то там сообщение что файл переехал и дается новый url.